# Presto - Count Occurrences of Strings in All Rows

Tags: sql, presto

I'm pretty new to Presto and am trying to write a query on the following table `colors`. I've tried using `flatten` and `histogram` but have not been successful. Could someone help me figure out how to accomplish this? Thanks!

```
row   words
0     yellow blue red
1     red
2     yellow red
```

words is a list of `varchar` right now.

Desired output:

```
word      count
yellow    2
red       3
blue      1
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
WITH
dataset AS (
  SELECT ARRAY
  [
    ARRAY['yellow','blue','red'],
    ARRAY['red'],
    ARRAY['yellow','red']
  ] AS words
)
SELECT words
FROM dataset
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to translate this into an array and then a table and count:

```
select w.word, count(*)
from t cross join
     unnest(split(t.words, ' ')) as w(word)
group by w.word;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I updated my question to include the code I have so far. I tried your suggestion and am getting `mismatched input 'UNNEST'`. Here's what I tried:
`SELECT w.word, count(*)
FROM dataset CROSS JOIN LATERAL
UNNEST(words) AS w(word)
GROUP BY w.word`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @felix_xiao . . . The `lateral` may be unnecessary.